# Renderplot and renderdatatable in the same output page

Tags: r, shiny

I have an issue here while executing this code. The logic is working perfectly. When you click on Values under "Factors under the datasets" the plots are displayed correctly. But when you click on Data table under "Factors under the datasets" the table is getting displayed at the bottom. Can I make it display at the top where plots were displayed earlier?

```
df <- structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 
                             5L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 2L), .Label = 
     c("asd", "dfg", "fgdsgd", 

     "fsd", "gdfgd", "gs", "sdfg", "sf"), class = 
   "factor"), B = c(29L, 

     24L, 
  46L, 50L, 43L, 29L, 32L, 24L, 35L, 39L, 33L, 47L, 53L, 26L, 

   31L), 
    C = structure(c(8L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 

   2L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 4L), .Label = c("asd", "er", "fg", "gf", "gfd", 

    "gfg", "qw", "sf", "tr"), class = "factor"), D = c(36L, 56L, 

  39L, 26L, 56L, 35L, 27L, 31L, 33L, 45L, 34L, 27L, 43L, 40L, 56L

  ), E = structure(c(9L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 

   10L, 9L, 9L, 5L), .Label = c("er", "fg", "g", "gd", "gf", "gfg", 

 "gtd", "qw", "sf", "tr"), class = "factor"), F = c(44L, 34L,  

    37L, 23L, 37L, 51L, 28L, 36L, 33L, 31L, 39L, 43L, 25L, 37L, 43L

   ), num = 1:15), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

theNames <- names(df)
  MyList  <- vector(mode = "list")
  for(i in theNames){
  MyList[[i]] <- df[,i]
}

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(tabPanel(
  "Factor_Bivariate_Analysis",
   sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
   fluidRow(
      column(h6(
  selectInput("se4", "Factors under the
              datasets", choices = c("", "Values","Data table"))
  ), width = 5, offset =
    0),
br(),
column(h6(
  actionButton("Val", "See the Values", width =
                 200, offset =
                 -1)
), width = 5, offset = 0),
br(),
column(h6(selectInput(
  "state", "Filters", choices = c("",MyList)
)), width = 5, offset = 0)
), width =
 1000
 ),
  mainPanel(
  h5(plotOutput(
  "Plot4", width = "1000px", height =
    "1000px"
), width = 1000), h5(dataTableOutput("Plot5"), width = 1000)
 ))
 )))


 server <- function(input, output, session) {
   f_data <- reactive({
     wanted_case <- input$state
     cat("selected case ", wanted_case, "\n\n")
     if (wanted_case == ""){
     fd <- df
  } else {
   fd <- df %>% filter_if(.predicate = is.factor,.vars_predicate = any_vars (. == 
                                                                          wanted_case))
print(fd)
  }
  return(fd)
   }) 
    Plot4 <- reactive({
     if (input$se4 == "Values") {
       print(ggplot(data = 
             f_data(),aes(x=num,y=B,fill=A))+geom_line()+facet_wrap("A",ncol=1,nrow=8, 
   scales = 
                                                                      "free"))
} else if (input$se4 == "NULL") {
 ""
 }
  })
    output$Plot4 <- renderPlot({
Plot4()
   })
   Plot5 <- reactive({
if (input$se4 == "Data table") {
print(data.frame(df))
} else if (input$se4 == "NULL") {
""
   }
       })
     output$Plot5 <- renderDataTable({
Plot5()
})
}

 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Note that I added the [tag:shiny] tag so your post will get noticed by more Shiny folks. You also might want to try cleaning up the indentation of your code; it's hard to trace opening brackets to their closing ones, and might help you in your own debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a combination of `uiOutput` and `renderUI`.

```
df <- structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 
                                     5L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 2L), .Label = 
                                     c("asd", "dfg", "fgdsgd", 

                                       "fsd", "gdfgd", "gs", "sdfg", "sf"), class = 
                                     "factor"), B = c(29L, 

                                                      24L, 
                                                      46L, 50L, 43L, 29L, 32L, 24L, 35L, 39L, 33L, 47L, 53L, 26L, 

                                                      31L), 
                     C = structure(c(8L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 

                                     2L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 4L), .Label = c("asd", "er", "fg", "gf", "gfd", 

                                                                     "gfg", "qw", "sf", "tr"), class = "factor"), D = c(36L, 56L, 

                                                                                                                        39L, 26L, 56L, 35L, 27L, 31L, 33L, 45L, 34L, 27L, 43L, 40L, 56L

                                                                     ), E = structure(c(9L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 

                                                                                        10L, 9L, 9L, 5L), .Label = c("er", "fg", "g", "gd", "gf", "gfg", 

                                                                                                                     "gtd", "qw", "sf", "tr"), class = "factor"), F = c(44L, 34L,  

                                                                                                                                                                        37L, 23L, 37L, 51L, 28L, 36L, 33L, 31L, 39L, 43L, 25L, 37L, 43L

                                                                                                                     ), num = 1:15), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

theNames <- names(df)
MyList  <- vector(mode = "list")
for(i in theNames){
  MyList[[i]] <- df[,i]
}

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(tabPanel(
    "Factor_Bivariate_Analysis",
    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(h6(
          selectInput("se4", "Factors under the
                      datasets", choices = c("", "Values","Data table"))
          ), width = 5, offset =
            0),
        br(),
        column(h6(
          actionButton("Val", "See the Values", width =
                         200, offset =
                         -1)
        ), width = 5, offset = 0),
        br(),
        column(h6(selectInput(
          "state", "Filters", choices = c("",MyList)
        )), width = 5, offset = 0)
        ), width =
        1000
      ),
      mainPanel(uiOutput("plots")
      ))
  )))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  f_data <- reactive({
    wanted_case <- input$state
    cat("selected case ", wanted_case, "\n\n")
    if (wanted_case == ""){
      fd <- df
    } else {
      fd <- df %>% filter_if(.predicate = is.factor,.vars_predicate = any_vars (. == 
                                                                                  wanted_case))
      print(fd)
    }
    return(fd)
  })

  output$plots <- renderUI({
    req(input$se4)
    if(input$se4 == "Values"){
      h5(plotOutput(
           "Plot4", width = "1000px", height =
             "1000px"
         ), width = 1000)
    }else if(input$se4 == "Data table"){
      h5(dataTableOutput("Plot5"), width = 1000)
    }
  })

  output$Plot4 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$se4,f_data())
    if (input$se4 == "Values") {
      print(ggplot(data = 
                     f_data(),aes(x=num,y=B,fill=A))+geom_line()+facet_wrap("A",ncol=1,nrow=8, 
                                                                            scales = 
                                                                              "free"))
    }
  })

  output$Plot5 <- renderDataTable({
    req(input$se4)
    if (input$se4 == "Data table") {
      data.frame(df)
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks but one question why do you have to call req(input$se4,f_data())? we can directly use right?

Comment: We could, its more of a force of habit for me. Its good to ensure the data you are using in a reactive expression actually exists. When an app gets more complicated this makes it easier to work with.